# How to search for questions that have any one of the multiple tags in a list?

Tags: support, tags, search

I'm trying to find questions that I can answer. So I reviewed advanced search help page, and I found `answers:0` which helps me avoid questions that already have answers and `locked:false` to avoid locked questions.

What I would like to do is limit questions to those that have one of the tags in a list. For example, if I search for `[python] [php]`, then I only get questions that have both tags. How do I get those that have either one?

Comment: When I was searching through meta, I didn't find that question. Looking at it now, it's more generic, and this one might be easier to find. Especially considering that one of the answers is that it's impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `or` operator.

From the [help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching):

> OR operator
>
> To combine results from multiple tags, separate the tag names (enclosed in square brackets) with the word "or": [widgets] or [geegaws] returns questions tagged with either tag.

Example [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+or+python) on Stack Overflow for `[php] or [python]`.

Works for more than two tags, as this example [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+or+python+or+javascript) `[php] or [python] or [javascript]` shows.

Example [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20or%20%5Bpython%5D%20or%20%5Bjavascript%5D%20closed%3Ano%20is%3Aquestion%20score%3A1%20hasaccepted%3Ano) with a more complex search term `[php] or [python] or [javascript] closed:no is:question score:1 hasaccepted:no`.

Comment: This works! And I just realized that it's on the help page. I was blind...

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no way to answer your question with a single search. However you can run 2 queries as in this sample:

- `[python] -[php] is:q` (= questions tagged with python and NOT tagged with php).
- `-[python] [php] is:q` (= questions tagged with php and NOT tagged with python).
- `[python] [php] is:q` (= questions tagged with php AND tagged with python).

And BTW, you may want to try a search variation like so:

`[python] -[php] closed:0  is:q score:1 hasaccepted:no`